# How to add series of dictionary with unknown number of keys

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, series, bitwise-and

I have created following dictionary `test`, consisting of `Series` objects:

```
test = {
    'A': pd.Series([True, False, True]),
    'B' : pd.Series([True,False,False])
}
```

I would like to perfrom `test['A'] & test['B']`. My problem is that I want to perfrom bit-wise addition for any possible number of keys in the dictionary. (I.e. it can be `'A'` or `'A' and 'B'` or `'A' and 'B' and 'C'` etc.). In any case, the value for each key has the same length, and all the `Series` are boolean.

Comment: Why not use a DataFrame?

Comment: Question: do you want to perform the bitwise of the KEYS or actually of the VALUES? When I read bitwise of the KEYS, I literally interpret as: 'A' | 'B'

Answer (score 1):

There are many advantages to working with a [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) instead of a dictionary of [`Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) objects. Converting from the latter to the former is trivial:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(test)
>>> df
       A      B
0   True   True
1  False  False
2   True  False
```

While the `DataFrame` constructor is pretty smart about parsing the input data, you could explicitly tell it you are initializing from a dictionary by using the [`from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html#pandas.DataFrame.from_dict) [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(test)
```

Now you can apply `&` using the [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html#pandas.DataFrame.all) method along any axis you want:

```
>>> df.all(axis=1) # going across
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

The same goes for `|` using [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html#pandas.DataFrame.any):

```
>>> df.any(axis=1)
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Indeed by converting to dataframe, it is straight forward. Many thanks!
I understand that Series do not provide this kind of manipulation in an easy way.

Comment: @NSK. They do, but not for an arbitrary number of them.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple one-line solution to your problem (if you want cumulative `and` operation over columns e.g. `A and B`, `A and B and C`, `A and B and C and D` and so on):

```
import pandas as pd

test = {
    "A": pd.Series([True, True, True]),
    "B": pd.Series([True, False, False]),
    "C": pd.Series([False, True, False]),
    "D": pd.Series([True, False, False]),
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(test)

# Here is da man    
print(df.cummin(axis="columns"))
```

Using `cummin`, if any value is `False`, all coming after it will be `False` as well as it's the smallest value.

Original dataframe:

```
      A      B      C      D
0  True   True  False   True
1  True  False   True  False
2  True  False  False  False
```

Cumulative `and`:

```
      A      B      C      D
0  True   True  False  False
1  True  False  False  False
2  True  False  False  False
```

First column is `A`, second is `A and B`, third `A and B and C`, last is `A and B and C and D`.